# A confusion regarding an infinite sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry this question might be unclear/coherent, but it baffles me logically.

Say we have an infinite sequence $\{x_i\}\forall i\in\Bbb{N}$. Can we choose every point in the sequence? Say we start from $x_1$, and choose every point after that; i.e. $x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots$. Remember that we're choosing the points individually, and not selecting the whole set $\{x_i\}$. Can we choose every point in $\{x_i\}$?

Say we choose a point $x_i$. Then there are infinite points $x_j$ left in $\{x_i\}$, $j>i$. This is true regardless of however high the value of $i$ is. I suppose the point $\lim _{n\to\infty}x_n$ can't be selected.

Let us suppose that we cannot select every point in $\{x_i\}$. When we say property $A$ is true for $\{x_i\}$, we prove it by saying "select any $x_i\in \{x_i\}$", and then prove it for $x_i$. Does this mean that there are point in $\{x_i\}$ for which property $A$ might not be true, **as those points can't be selected in such a fashion**?

Thanks in advance! An exposition on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you **exactly** mean by "choosing"? What do you mean by "the point $\,\lim x_n\,$ "? This point exists as a real/complex/whatever "point" iff the original sequence converges finitely.

Comment: Choosing is 'selecting'. I have read multiple proofs of the form "select an x\in\{x_i\}$. And the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Then I don't understand either your question or the problem, @Ayush : if you want to pick up a specific element of a given sequence just go by the element's index...and I still don't understand why you believe the point $\,\lim x_n\,$ can't be "selected" *if* we know the sequence's limit exists and what the limit is....and still can't I see why you think there can exist a sequence where not every point in it can be selected...

Comment: I suppose this exposes my concerns well: Let us take an infinite sequence $\{x_i\}$ convergent to $l$. For any point $x_i\in\{x_i\}$, we can prove that it does not exist in every open set containing $l$ (proof: let $d(l,x_i)=\epsilon$. Then $x_i\notin d(l,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$). Does that mean no point of $\{x_i\}$ is contained within every open set containing $l$. This would go against the definition of a convergent sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a property, and let's consider it as a Boolean function on the points of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.  That is $A(x_n)=$ true if $x_n$ has property $A$, and $A(x_n)=$ false if $x_n$ does not have property $A$.  Suppose also we can prove the implication:

$$\left(x_i\in\{x_n\}\right)\Longrightarrow (A(x_i)=\text{ true})$$

Notice this implication states that property $A$ holds for all values of the sequence $x_i$.  In proving this is true, we didn't have to select every element individually, we just prove it for a general representative $x_i$.  As long as we don't assume anything special about $x_i$, except that it is a member of $\{x_n\}$, then the above implication shows that $x_i$ has property $A$.

As a simple example, let $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=3$, $\ldots$, $x_n=n$, $\ldots$.  Notice that if $x_i\in\{x_n\}$, then $x_i=i>0$.  It follows that every member of the sequence is positive, because every member is of the form $x_i$ for some $i$, and we just showed it is true for arbitrary $i$.

Edit (to address comments about convergence):

Let's play a game with the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$.  First, you choose a point in the sequence, and then I try to choose a ball around $0$ not containing this point.  If I can do this, I win; if not, I lose.  Who wins this game?  As you've shown in the comments, I do.

Now, let's try another game.  I'll first pick a ball around $0$, and then you try to exhibit a value $N$ such that $x_n$ is always in this ball as long as $n>N$.  If you can do this, you win, otherwise you lose.  You'll quickly see that you should be able to win this game, precisely because the sequence converges to $0$.

Notice the first game shows that no single point of the sequence is contained in every ball around $0$, and the second game shows that any ball around $0$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence.  These two statements are not contradictory.

Comment: Let us take an infinite sequence $\{x_i\}$ convergent to $l$. For any point $x_i\in\{x_i\}$, we can prove that it does not exist in every open set containing $l$ (proof: let $d(l,x_i)=\epsilon$. Then $x_i\notin d(l,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$). Does that mean no point of $\{x_i\}$ is contained within every open set containing $l$. This would go against the definition fo convergent sequence. $x_i$ is also a general representative of the elements of $\{x_i\}$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: First, if $x_i=l$, then it will be contained in every open set containing $l$, because the two are the same point.  This is indeed possible.  Next, if $x_i\ne l$ then your proof correctly shows that $x_i$ is not in every open set containing $l$, however, this in no way contradicts the definition of convergence.  A sequence converges to $l$ if and only if for any ball around $l$, there is a point beyond which the sequence always remains inside the ball.  These statements are not contradictory, see my edit.

Comment: You are right. Showing that one selected point is not present inside every open ball containing $l$ does not show that the series is not convergent. However this was just to mirror the fact that most proofs prove a property for any arbitrary point of a sequence, and then say it is true for every point in the sequence. Is this not the method they follow?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: Yes, that is a fine method to follow to prove certain things about a sequence, for instance, that all of its members are positive (see my answer).  However, this is not how one proves convergence of a sequence, because the definition of convergence of a sequence doesn't require all of the elements of the sequence to have any property.  Instead, it requires all balls around the limit point to have a certain property.  So we have to prove a statement for all possible balls, not all possible members of the sequence.  This is why convergence proofs start with "let $\epsilon >0$."

Comment: lol the point just hit home. Thanks tons!

Answer (score 0):

@Ayush, I'd rather choose another wording to address your concern in your last comment below your question: given

$$x_i\in\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;\;\text{and}\;\;l:=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\;,\;\;\text{let}\;\;\epsilon:=|l-x_i|$$

and assume $\,x_i\ne l\implies \epsilon>0\;$ , then we get that

$$x_i\notin\left\{x\in\Bbb R\;;\;|l-x|<\frac\epsilon2\right\}=:B\left(l\,,\,\frac\epsilon2\right)$$

and thus we can say that in any neighborhood of the limit $\;l\;$ there exist elements of the sequence that aren't contained in it...but this, of course, does **not** contradict the definition of limit which implies that  *any* neighborhood of the purposed limit **must** contain *all the elements of the sequence **except** perhaps a finite number of them* ...which is precisely what happens here.

Comment: @DonAntonio- Thanks for the answer. My actual concern was slightly different, which came out only in my convo with Jared.